# How do I evaluate integrals that involve the signum ($\text{sgn}$) function?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, trigonometry, definite-integrals

For example, I want to evaluate $$ \displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} \left| \sin x \right| \text{ d}x $$ and I already know that: $$ \displaystyle \begin{aligned} \int \left| \sin x \right| \text{ d}x & = \int \sin x \text{ sgn}\left( \sin x \right) \text{ d}x \\ & = -\cos x \text{ sgn}\left( \sin x \right) + \mathcal{C} \end{aligned}$$ How would I evaluate the definite integral involving the signum function?

Comment: break the interval of integration into parts on which you know the sign of your function - $[0,\pi]$ and $[\pi, 2\pi]$ in this example

Comment: see where sine function is positive or...

Comment: In your second equality, you cannot pull out $\text{sgn} (\sin x)$ because it is a function (not a constant).

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm wondering whether it was ok for me to pull out the signum function of my integral. It doesn't seem right having looked at it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Instead of trying to use the sign function, break up the integral into intervals where $\sin x \geq 0$ and $\sin x < 0$. On such intervals, $|\sin x|$ is particularly simple and easier to integrate.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm already aware of this method but I wanted to know more about the signum function w.r.t. (pun not intended) integrals :-)

Comment: Well this method is really how you should deal with the signum function (see John's comment).

Answer (score 2):

**HINT :**
$$
\int_{0}^{\large 2\pi} \left| \sin x \right|\ dx=\int_{0}^{\large\pi}\sin x\ dx-\int_{\large\pi}^{\large2\pi}\sin x\ dx.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $x = u + \pi \to dx = du$, and $sinx = -sinu$. Thus:

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} |sinx|dx = \displaystyle \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |sinu|du$.

Observe that $f(u) = |sinu|$ is an even function, so:

$\displaystyle \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |sinu|du = 2\displaystyle \int_{0}^\pi |sinu|du = 2\displaystyle \int_{0}^\pi sinudu = (-2cosu)|_{u=0}^\pi = 4$.